# store an array in db

Tags: php, arrays

I have a page with 24 different buttons.

When the user logs in I have to check if he has the right to click the button and activate that specific functionality. So what I thought is to store an array with 24 items made this way:

```
[0]=>'yes',
[1]=>'no
```

and so on for all the buttons.

When I retrieve this array from the db at login I store it in $_SESSION array and then for each button I can do

```
if($_SESSION['right'][0]=='yes'){
    //show the button
}else{
    //hide the button
}
```

The array will be stored in a table where there will be all the different user profiles (so each array will exist only once) and each user will have a join to the profile id.

What will be the best way to store the array in the db? Or I miss a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Create table users, create a table options, create a table options_per_users with user_id and option_id and store it that way

Comment: Yes, I know I can do this way but I already have a very heavily loaded db and I'd like to make it easier. With my approach I retrieve just one row per user for all the options. Your way I retrieve 24 items from the db.

Comment: You can encode your array as a JSON object (which is simply a string) to be saved in the DB and then decoded to retrieve the data back (JSON to array). Have a look at json_encode and json_decode in the php.net website :)

Comment: Thanks @Teknotica but what data type will you put in the db structure to store the json? Btw, I already use json_* functionalities.

Comment: It all depends of how long it's the string (JSON). Could be just a VARCHAR :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) your array and insert it in a varchar field in mysql, and later when you need it, fetch it from db and [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it. But much better way would be to make your tables relational.

Comment: Yes I know. The db is relational but for this task I'd like to keep it simple and retrieve just one more field in the query I already do. The db is already heavily loaded by the application

Comment: @LelioFaieta In that case you can either use serialize/unserialize or json_encode/json_decode methods for data storage and retrieval, setting varchar as datatype for the column you store the data on.

Comment: Using varchar also for json? Isn't there a specific data type for json in mysql?

Comment: @LelioFaieta As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type, see:: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html but for prior versions you need to stick to varchar

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [bitmask approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))

You can store up to 32 or 64 (on 64 bit systems) values in a single integer.

Each of your buttons would have a number 2^n where n is the button index. The resulting number is the sum of all active button numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same way in some CMS like Wordpress and OpenCart.

Array stored as serialized string.
So, you can use 
serialize($array_value) 
to insert, and 
$array_value = unserialize($row['field1']) to select.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store your data like that in a DB. That goes against the purpose of a DB.

Create a table for permissions with the user id as foreign key, and then add a `INT(1) UNSIGNED` column for each permission. Zero means no, one means yes.

Comment: As I already said in other comments this is made with the goal to just fetch one more field in an already existing query. The db is already heavily loaded. The db is a relational one for all the core functionalities

Comment: I still advise against it.